# project configuration error after android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android studio, my project won't show activity_main.xml.
Clicking on the warning button shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDYT4.png). I changed nothing in the project i just updated Android studio.

here is wahts in my build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

any Tips? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart`. Then re-sync with gradle after restart. If that doesn't work, it might help to clean the project as well. (`Build -> Clean Project`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just reinstalled everything, it works now, but I have this little error in activity_main.xml: Render error